# Why Cannot find control with name: 'username' only randomly?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular2-changedetection

I have an Angular reactive form with works most of the time. But sometimes, randomly, I get an error

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'username'
    at _throwError (forms.js:2337)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2245)
    at FormGroupDirective.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5471)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6072)
    at FormControlName.push../node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm5/forms.js.FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5993)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:21093)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:29495)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:29457)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:30091)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:30051)
```

The component is a simple login page, HTML is

```
<div id="loginSection" class="middle-dashboard-box">
  <div class="login-title content-inner-title" i18n="logintitle|@@loginheader">Login</div>
  <form class="login-form" [formGroup]="loginFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="login($event)">
    <mymat-form-error></mymat-form-error>
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="login-input input-control-width">
        <input matInput formControlName="username" i18n-placeholder="Username|@@username" placeholder="Username">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div>
      <mat-form-field class="login-input input-control-width"> 
        <input matInput formControlName="password" type="password" i18n-placeholder="Password|@@password" placeholder="Password">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class="forgot-pass">
      <a href="#public/forgotpassword" i18n="forgot password|@@forgotPasswordLink">Forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="main-btn login-btn"
      i18n="Login|Login button action@@login">Login</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and TS is

```
@Component( {
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
} )
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    loginFormGroup: FormGroup;

    constructor( private router: Router,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private loginService: LoginService ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loginFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group( {
            username: ['', Validators.required],
            password: ['', Validators.required]
        } );
        this.loginFormGroup.controls['username'].setValue( this.loginService.latestUsername );
    }

    login( event ) {
        // do login stuff, not relevant here
    }
}
```

`this.loginService.latestUsername` points to a getter in the LoginService:

```
get latestUsername(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem( LoginService.LATESTUSERNAME_KEY ) || ''
}
```

The `FormControlName.ngOnChanges` in the stacktrace makes me think ng is running a change detection before the control is properly initialized, but as there is no subscription or similar around, I don't see what could be triggering it.
I'm observing the error during Selenium tests (there reliably on some tests, intermittently on others), but have had it once or twice while clicking around manually. The effect only occurs since upgrading to Angular 8.2.14 (from 7)

Comment: I'd set the `setValue(...)` to AfterViewInit to make sure the controls are rendered before accessing. Not 100% it'll solve, but easy quick to try.

Comment: Looks like a bug with the test. Or maybe a version mismatch somewhere? Nothing here is problematic. Generally I put my form construction in the constructor but this should still be ok. Angular 8 has been mature for some time now. If there was an intermittent bug in something this common it would’ve been caught by someone

Comment: I completely removed the `setValue` on the username, still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts) of `FormControlName` and thinking about [when ngOnChanges() can run](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), I reckon `ngOnChanges()` is running before `ngOnInit()` has finished building the form.

To diagnose this, I would litter both `ngOnChanges()` and `ngOnInit()` with `console.log()` to trace what's going on.

To get around the problem (if this is the cause), it should be as simple as guarding the form with `*ngIf` to make sure the directives aren't prematurely triggering change detection. Ideally you could also use `OnPush` change detection strategy.

Comment: I'll mark this as the solution, as it helped me find the root cause. My login form uses a custom `mymat-form-error`. This component subscribes to errors, and displays them in the UI. The key point was that during **construction** of the login form component, the `mymat-form-error` triggered a `this.cdRef.detectChanges();`.

Comment: This seemingly being the solution, mind explaining further, I am not sure I can follow this to a solution.

Comment: @HlawulekaMAS The root of the problem is that some directives are running before the component has finished initialising. The general solution is to hide child components with `*ngIf`, where your code looks something like `<child *ngIf="ready"></child>`, where `ready` is only set to a truthy value once all dependencies have been loaded. Could you set up a stackblitz that represents your problem and post here?

Comment: Thanks, BTW, I finally resolved my issue after days of struggle. The issue was indeed to do with my form not being ready, at times. I hate that there is no one size fits all for this problem.

What I also had to do was to pause the code that would show the template until I knew for a fact that I had prepared my form controls, i.e build the form in some code segment and emit a value to show that the form is ready, then do the rest of the logic including resolving the `*ngIf` variable to true, then.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private loginService: LoginService
) {
    this.loginFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginFormGroup.get('username').setValue(this.loginService.latestUsername);
}
```

---

**Update:**

Is a good practice keep your constructor clean, for that you can create a function to create the form like this example:

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private loginService: LoginService
) {
    this._createForm();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginFormGroup.get('username').setValue(this.loginService.latestUsername);
}

private _createForm(): void {
    this.loginFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        username: ['', Validators.required],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```